# PostGIS update column with selected

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, database, pgadmin-4

I am new to database sorry if this is basic.

I have selected point geometry from a geometry column in pgAdmin, however, I would like to know how to now copy the selected points to a new column?

This is my script used to select the POINT geometry

```
SELECT count(*) from public.test1  where GeometryType(geometry) = 'POINT'
```

so my update set might be something like

```
UPDATE test1 SET GeometryType(geometry) = 'POINT' = newcolumn;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to copy the geometry, you would add a new geometry column then copy the selected records. Assuming your data is using SRID 4326:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN geom_point geometry(point,4326); 

UPDATE myTable 
SET geom_point  = geometry
WHERE GeometryType(geometry) = 'POINT';
```

If you want to record the geometry type, then you need to add a text column:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN geom_type TEXT; 

UPDATE myTable 
SET geom_type =  GeometryType(geometry) 
WHERE GeometryType(geometry) = 'POINT';
```

Comment: dude,  you're quite on fire in the *PostGIS* tag...take my +1 and have a happy 10.000 rep day ,)

Comment: much deserved. now go moderating and leave some questions to us...,)